# Knockout 2.0 Unable to parse bindings

Tags: javascript, apache, netbeans, knockout.js, osx-elcapitan

Recently I got a  bunch of code from another developer that I should use building other functionalities. Unfortunate I am not really able to run it locally. The weird thing is that the portal that i should use  works perfectly on the server but when I'm trying to run it locally I am getting the following exception

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier;
Bindings value: css: {
                                         'make-primary':(lala.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().resultsetLength() > 0 && !lala.viewModels.transacQuickactionsViewModel.operationInProgress() && (lala.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().captureButtonIsEnabled() || lala.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().refundButtonIsEnabled()Â || lala.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().abortButtonIsEnabled())),
```

A weird thing that I have noticed is that around .refundButtonIsEnabled() block a weird character ("Â") is shown, character that is invisible to my code until i use google chrome dev console tool. Therefore my theory is that there might be something wrong with my localhost setting.

In order to run this code I am using:

1. Mac OSX El capitan
2. Netbeans 8.1
3. Apache 2 (httpd24)
4. Grunt that runs the code without any errors
5. Knockout 2.0

And my html code is:

```
<div class="span6 actions-panel-bottom" data-bind="css: {
                                         'make-primary': (lalal.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().resultsetLength() > 0 && !lalal.viewModels.transacQuickactionsViewModel.operationInProgress() && (lalal.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().captureButtonIsEnabled() || lalal.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().refundButtonIsEnabled()|| lalal.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().abortButtonIsEnabled()))">
```

And

```
'parseBindingsString': function(bindingsString, bindingContext, node) {
        try {
            var bindingFunction = createBindingsStringEvaluatorViaCache(bindingsString, this.bindingCache);
            return bindingFunction(bindingContext, node);              
        } catch (ex) {
            throw new Error("Unable to parse bindings.\nMessage: " + ex + ";\nBindings value: " + bindingsString);
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to mention that before the code fails, several other bindings will run successfully and will stop at 'make-primary' and it will add this weird character.

Thank you in advanced! If you have any tips in how to debug this situation  i would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related specifically to KO 2.0. I get an error there, but not in 3.0. It's a pretty God-awful binding. As a rule, bindings should be simple expressions, and complex expressions should be in your viewmodel.

Is there a reason you can't update Knockout versions?

The snippet below is just a minimal repro. Copy it to a new snippet and watch the console as you change versions and Run it.

```js
ko.applyBindings({});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="span6 actions-panel-bottom" data-bind="css: {
                                         'make-primary': (lalal.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().resultsetLength() > 0 && !lalal.viewModels.transacQuickactionsViewModel.operationInProgress() && (lalal.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().captureButtonIsEnabled() || lalal.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().refundButtonIsEnabled()|| lalal.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().abortButtonIsEnabled()))"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Roy, Thank you for the answer! to answer your question:
-Unfortunate the project is quite complex and has a lot of dependencies. Even though, i have tried to change the version for test purposes as you suggested but i have the same error. 

What is intriguing me is that in the end of the following condition  satadmin.viewModels.transacFilterTabsViewModel.getSyncList().refundButtonIsEnabled()Â || a weird character is shown that i can't see it in the code... The character is a Danish one therefore I'm thinking that there might be something wrong with the server configuration.

Comment: P.s: I have looked for invisible characters in Netbeans and i couldn't see anything besides space

Comment: That part I have no idea about, sorry.